# firefox hover opacity

Tags: css, opacity

I can't get hover opacity to change in firefox or IE. it's working in chrome. Firefox and IE is able to work with opacity initial state as defined in .move, but just not on hover. Any ideas.

```
<style>
.move{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:0.2;
  filter:alpha(opacity=20);
  }
.move:hover{
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  }
</style>

<div class="move"></div>
```

Comment: Is your `move` div really empty?

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/gWKEQ

Comment: Can anyone confirm it works locally with firefox. It works for me on jsfiddle, but not when testing it locally with firefox.

Comment: I'm close to figuring it out, I think.  It does not work with me locally with firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug: http://support.mozilla.com/pa-IN/questions/746770

The quick fix is replacing:

```
.move:hover{
```

with

```
[class="move"]:hover{
```

Use the script found at http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html to address IE quirks.

Final code is

```
<style>
 body {
  behavior:url('csshover3.htc');
 }

.move{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:0.2;
  filter:alpha(opacity=20);
  -moz-opacity:0.2;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.2;
  }
.move:hover{
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  -moz-opacity:1.0;
  -khtml-opacity: 1.0;
  }
[class="move"]:hover{
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  -moz-opacity:1.0;
  -khtml-opacity: 1.0;
  }
</style>

<div class="move"></div>
```

You need to add -moz-opacity and -khtml-opacity to support webkit and older firefox installations.

Comment: This works in FF, and i see it's a bug, But that still doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score -1):

opacity rule is all wacked in ie. ie7 and 6 doesnt support them.
i couldnt see any reason that y it didnt work on FF.