# -moz-transition working in chrome but not in firefox safari ie please help me

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox, css

My code is as following:

```
.Frozenbg
{
    background-image:url('Images/Frozen.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transition: background 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 1s linear; /* Firefox*/
    -webkit-transition: background 1s linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: background 1s linear; /* Opera */
}
```

The problem is that I am adding class on hover and its working great which means it adds the class having background image with fade in effect that looks good, but the fade in /transition effect is not going on firefox and other browser please help me I am stuck in this problem from last night.

Answer (score 1):

Transitions of background-image are not part of the spec yet.  There's a proposal to do cross-fade for them, but it's still a pretty early draft.

Answer (score 0):

> Turns out there is a bug in Firefox (firefox hover opacity).

[CSS3 transition/hover effect not working in Firefox; a Firefox bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309691/css3-transition-hover-effect-not-working-in-firefox-a-firefox-bug)