# Slider transition doesn't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transitions

I created an example here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/oyjlyupw

Even though the transition is defined for firefox, it doesn't seem to animate in my Firefox 21.0 at least.
I've tried lots of permutations and putting the transition properties on different elements, but I can't seem to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add a starting left position to `.slider-button`

For example:

```
left:0;
```

Updated: [**CSSDeck demo**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/77j7tttu)

Have a read through this - 
**[CSS3 transition/hover effect not working in Firefox; a Firefox bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309868/2470724)**