# Image disappears only in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to have an image become slightly opaque when the mouse hovers over it. I use this line of code in php.

```
  <img src="/wp-content/themes/Map/images/SlideTab/slide2.png"  onmouseover= 'shade(this)' onmouseout = 'normal(this)'  onclick='showSubMenu("sm_item3")'  alt ="Slide" style ="height :22em ; width:4.063em; "/>
```

The shade function just changes the opacity to 0.5 .The image acts appropiately in all browsers except firefox. In firefox the images goes opaque and if the mouse stays over the image, the image will disappear. I have been unable to locate the issue. Thanks in advance for any advise.

here is my shade function. Very simple. It works in all browsers. It even works with firefox. The difference is in firefox after going opaque the image goes away completely:

```
function shade(x) {     
    x.style.opacity = ".5";   
}
```

Comment: I've removed the PHP tag, as this question isn't anything to do with it. You might want to add your `shade()` function to the question, and retag it as jquery or javascript.

Comment: can you try  `x.style.opacity = 0.5;` without the quotes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: Just tried it. No diference

Comment: Seems a bug see this question for answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686997/firefox-hover-opacity  ..also a fiddle you can test on other browsers http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tnDaD/

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on a lib like JQuery and its API. Look at [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method for instance. If you still want to use your own method, please paste it in the question.

Cheers.

Comment: fadeTo() yields the same result. Image disappears completely even when 0.5 opacity is specified.

Comment: I tried of Firefox 21 with your method and it works fine. What version of Firefox are you targeting?

Comment: Testing in Firefox 22.0